# Is publicist degree honored according to one shared question or many?

Tags: discussion, advertising

In comments to question

- [What is the difference between 20$ and $20?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11326/3085)

[Michael Mrozek](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/849/michael-mrozek) informed about [publicist badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges) that:

> You have to get [1000 unique IP views
>   in 5 days (vgv8 - this is the link to a list
>   of publicists)](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges); this post only has
>   378 views total (who knows how many
>   are from your link)

Is this badge given according to IP views to a single question shared by a candidate for this degree or (m)any?

Comment: I spoke with Rebecca Chernoff, one of the community coordinators, who said that this question is indeed on topic for a child meta site. Reopened and deleted all the irrelevant discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 question, 1 user,  5 days, 1000 unique IP views. 1 badge.

However, you must first attain the Announcer and Booster badges, and not on the same question.

Comment: wow, thanks, that short answer for that complicated chainy conditionals